# BitBucket API v2 - Adding Users at Groups

Tags: bitbucket

Today I used the BitBucket API v1 to add users to groups of my team on BitBucket. API v1 will be discontinued later this year (12/31/18) and this functionality is not available in the v2 documentation.

Is there any way to add users to groups within BitBucket other than through v1?

API v1 endpoint: `https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/groups/{team}/{group-name}/members/{username}`
API v2 documentation: `https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/`

Comment: This is a good question for BitBucket technical support as it relates specifically to a product, not programming.

Comment: I hope there is an answer for this question. we also use user groups endpoint and we need to keep it in v2

Comment: It doesn't exist currently. https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22597